# nginx forward the clients ip and port

Tags: nginx

I have nginx acting as a load balancer.

I have 3 servers running behind the nginx and redis running for the 3 servers.

They are all running in docker images on the same ubuntu instance.

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM**:
I need to record the users ip and port for future use. But both webSockets and udp returns:

```
0.0.0.0:0
```

This is bad obviously. There has to be a way to forward the clients information. I am guessing this is a header of some kind and nginx can utilize it?

edit - current config:

nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 7;

# server context

events { worker_connections 1024; }

# Load balance WS traffic across the three servers
http {

    upstream node-app {
    least_conn;
    server node1:8080 weight=25 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server node2:8080 weight=25 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server node3:8080 weight=25 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://node-app;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    }

}

# Load balance UDP-based DNS traffic across the three servers
stream {

  upstream node-app-udp {
    least_conn;
    server node1:1337;
    server node2:1337;
    server node3:1337;
  }

  server {
      listen          1337 udp;
      listen          1337; #tcp
      proxy_pass      node-app-udp;
      proxy_timeout   3s;
      proxy_responses 3;
  }

}
```

Comment: post your current config please

Comment: updated! :) Sorrry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not forward the IP in request headers you send back to your nodes.
A nice approach would be to set a least in your **location** block :

```
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;  
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
```

Comment: no luck. :(
proxy_bind $remote_addr:$remote_port transparent;
and it works, but fails (responce 500) on delivery.

Comment: Please describe more exactly how it fails, and what do the log files tell.

Comment: thank you. This ended up being right, however for some reason with my build I have to specify "user root" at the top.

Comment: You shouldn't run nginx with root user account...